# Open New Activity from Android Button Click

Tags: java, android, button

In my app I'm developing in android studio, I'm making a button to redirect from one activity to another but it does not give me anything even though I do not have any errors in the code.

```
package com.example.shreeganesha.splash;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_beatness);
    init();
}
    public Button btn2;

 public void init(){
         btn2= (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn2);
         btn2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

               Intent inf= new Intent(beatness.this,Informacoes.class);

              startActivity(inf);
            }
      });
}
```

Comment: Your code is correct.Please check the id of your button.

Comment: the id of the button is changeActivity

Comment: If the id of the botton is changeActivity then why you write btn2 in findViewById?
Change it to btn2=(Button)findViewById(R.id.changeActivity);
This will solve your problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your id's on your xml layout, also check there is no onClick XML property being used that can be conflicting with your button, check that your new activity name and that your new activity is correctly linked to the intended layout

```
package com.example.shreeganesha.splash;

    private Button changeActivity; //Try more explicit names on your variables instead of just btn2, 
    // also declare your variables on top for better organized code

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_beatness);
        init();
    }


    public void init(){
        changeActivity = (Button)findViewById(R.id.changeActivity);
        changeActivity.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i = new Intent(this, YourNewActivityClass.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });
    }
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Also present the same problem, i also create a new activity with the name that you put just for example and it gives me that Cannot resolve constructor 'intent (anonymous android.view.View.OnClickListener,java.lang.Class<com.example.shreeganesha.splash.YourNewActivityClass>)'

Answer (score 0):

Try to declared it on your manifest file your "Informacoes" class as an activity.

Try to organize your code better as well. It's very messy.

Comment: Thx for the advice for the organization, but it´s already declared on manifest. The app run fine but when it comes to click on that button nothing happen.